# Mysql query returns duplicate results for each record

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am not a sql guru but I have three tables that I added a foreign key to each (maybe thats where the problem is)

```
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|   DISTINCT_DEALER   |    |  DISTINCT_CUSTOMER  |   |    CUSTOMER_SALES   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|      d_id   (pk)    |    |       d_id          |   |        d_id         |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_address   |    |     dealer_name     |   |   customer_number   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_city      |    |   customer_number   |   |    total_sales      |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_state     |    |    customer_name    |
|---------------------|    |---------------------| 
|    dealer_zip       |    |    customer_email   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|
```

I have a FK for distinct_customers d_id ref on distinct_dealer d_id and a FK on customer sales on d_id referencing distinct_dealer d_id.

when I run this query below, it returns every record duplicate 54 times (number of total records for that one d_id.

```
select d.d_id, d.dealer_name, cs.total_sales from dship d
join cs_sales cs on d.d_id = cs.d_id order by d.d_id
```

It looks like its returning a record for each d_id, can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select d.d_id, d.dealer_name,
       sum(cs.total_sales)
from dship d join
     cs_sales cs
     on d.d_id = cs.d_id 
group by d.d_id;
```

Comment: yes but I am also trying to bring in each sale per customer.  With that query, it sums the dealership sales per dealership.  What I want to do is list each Dealership with its customer name and each sale per customer.